# Uploading picture in Laravel Registration

Tags: php, image, laravel, upload, registration

I'm making a website where users can upload their own profile picture, with their credentials such as name, email, password, and dob using Laravel Authentication.

After doing `php artisan make:auth` , there's this function in `AuthController.php` :

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'dob' => $data['dob'],
        'profile_picture' => $data['profile_picture],
    ]);
}
```

and here's my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-mail Address</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

        @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
             </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

        @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
        <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">

        @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Fullname</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">

        @if ($errors->has('name'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('dob') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Date of Birth</label>
        <input id="dateOfBirth" type="date" class="form-control" name="dob">

        @if ($errors->has('dob'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('dob') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

     <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('profile_picture') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Profile Picture</label>
        <input id="profilePicture" type="file" class="form-control" name="profile_picture">

        @if ($errors->has('profile_picture'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('profile_picture') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i> Register
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I would like to save the image filename with its extension. But how do I do it?
How to get only his filename in string, move the image file to public folder, and save it into XAMPP database?

Comment: Just to clear something out. In reality You are not saving the image into DB! You are saving only the "string" path to that image on your server!

Comment: @lewis4u yes! That's exactly what I want! Only the string aka the filename.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to save the name and upload to public directory in profile_images folder, then you can do something like this:

```
protected function create(array $data)

{
     $request = request();

     $profileImage = $request->file('profile_picture');
     $profileImageSaveAsName = time() . Auth::id() . "-profile." . $profileImage->getClientOriginalExtension();

     $upload_path = 'profile_images/';
     $profile_image_url = $upload_path . $profileImageSaveAsName;
     $success = $profileImage->move($upload_path, $profileImageSaveAsName);


      return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'dob' => $data['dob'],
            'profile_picture' => $profile_image_url,
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain from where request() function comes from. data is being passed to create function through $data variable so I am unable to understand  $request = request(); code.

Comment: I used request helper here. From the Laravel doc 
" request()
The request function returns the current request instance or obtains an input item:

$request = request(); "

Comment: Thanks, I was looking this function under request section but as u mentioned,Iwas able to find it under helper section

Comment: I think the upload path should be like as below:
`$destinationPath = storage_path('app/public/profile_images');`

Comment: I don't know if the threat its closed but I just see this problem in my project, but what happen if the image is optional? this its the code that I used in other controllers if ($request->hasFile('image')){
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $name_image = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path().'/images/',$name_imagen);
        } in this code if a want a image do something, but if I don't then don't save it, with the code in the answer send me this error: "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null"

Comment: I tried your code. It can also work without the request helper? `$data['profile_picture']` can be used here then why request helper?

Answer (score 0):

by getting Extension and set file name you can move your file into a public folder and save the data 
**here is create function save file**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $file_extention = $data['img_profile']->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file_name = time().rand(99,999).'image_profile.'.$file_extention;
    $file_path = $data['img_profile']->move(public_path().'/users/image',$file_name);

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'dob' => $data['dob'],
        'profile_picture' => $file_path, // save full image path to database
    ]);
}
```

I hope this helps you