# Array to string conversion using laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

i added some fields to users table of laravel auth, and when i want to create a new user it gives me error Call to a member function hasFile () on array.

**RegisterController.php**

```
protected function create(array $data)
    { 
        $jdate = Carbon::now();
        //image
          if($data->hasFile('image'))
       {
        $image = $data->file('image');
        $imagee = Crypt::encryptString($image);
        $image->storeAs("public\annonces\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year,$imagee.'.'.$image->extension());
        $data->image = "annonces\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year."\\".$imagee.'.'.$image->extension(); 
        }
        //images
        $dataim = array();
         if($data->hasFile('images'))
         {
            foreach($data->file('images') as $file)
            {
                $namee = "public\\annonces\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year."\\".time().'.'.$file->extension(); 
                $name = Crypt::encryptString($namee).'.'.$file->extension();
                $file->storeAs("public\\annonces\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year, $name);  
                array_push($dataim,$name);
            }
         }
         $data->images=json_encode($dataim);
        return User::create([
            'name'       => $data['name'],
            'email'      => $data['email'],
            'password'   => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'telephone'  => $data['telephone'], 
            'ville'      => $data['ville'], 
            'ighrem'     => $data['ighrem'], 
            'autrei'     => $data['autrei'] ?? null, 
            'hay'        => $data['hay'], 
            'autreh'     => $data['autreh'] ?? null, 
            'adressem'   => $data['adressem'], 
            'adresser'   => $data['adresser'],
            'image'      => $data['image'] ?? null,
            'images'     => $data['images'] ?? null
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: You can see in the signature of the `create` method that `$data` is an array and not a request object. So you can't use the request method on it.

Comment: `$data` is not an object in this case, but it's an array as you stated in the arguments of your `create` method, which is why you're receiving the error.

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Kindly check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47857810/14066311 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/61504699/14066311

Comment: @user3478148 thx for u answer I want to insert links of images in database and images in public folder \ storage \ adverts \ September2020

Answer (score 0):

May you use as below

```
protected function create(Request $data){}
```